# Multi page crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, crystal-reports

I'm working with MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Crystal Reports. It is a WPF project on .NET 4.0.

There is a 1 page crystal report in the project which is used in a section. The data comes from an XML file. Now a batch processing needs to be implemented. There could be N >= 1 number of XML files. For each N file, the same 1 page crystal report will be used to generate an N page report. The i-th page of the report will show data from i-th XML file. How this can be done?

I'm new to Crystal Reports so please explain elaborately.

Comment: To clarify - you want to (a) populate a one-page crystal report with data from an XML file, and (b) automate doing this N times with different XML. Then (c) hook all this up to your project to display each generated report as a page.  Which of these are you asking for help with? It'd be useful to provide info on what you've done/tried already and what it is exactly that you're stuck with - as is, this question is very broad...

Comment: @Chris: Not sure how to narrow it down. From your comment, (a) is done and I can generate 1 page report and display the report in a window. I am looking for a way to generate N page report and display the report in a window! This is probably a silly thing to ask, but I'm very new to Crystal Reports.

Comment: Ok - I understood the original question as wanting to generate N 1-page-reports, not an N-page report. Very different things ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to combine the xml files in one big xml file and to use a group inside the report to separate the cases. This will allow you to set the datasource once and the report will generate N pages - one for each record in the xml file. 
If you want to use the current report without changes you can create a loop, which will run the report for each xml file , generate a PDF file and at the end of the cycle merge all PDF files in one big file.

Comment: The second approach seems convenient. But how can I generate PDF files and merge them in crystal reports?

Comment: You can create a PDF using the export method of reportdocument object. Keep all exported documents in an array or collection and at the end of the process use a component like iTextSharp to combine all files